# SQL Server Reporting Services Standard Edition report against SQL Server Express database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, sql-server-2005-express

I want to know if SQL Server Reporting Services Standard Edition is capable of running a report against a SQL Server Express database.

In addition if its possible to schedule reports against a SQL Server Express database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Reporting Services doesn't care about where it gets data from.

Scheduling is handled by the SQL Server used by Reporting Services for its metadata. Nothing to with the source of the user data (Express in this case).